# Get alternative text and source attributes of an image using JavaScript (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following markup:

```
<h1 id="logoImage">
    <a href="/">
        <img src="http://path-to-image.jpg" alt="Title of site" />
    </a>
</h1>
```

I would like to get the values of "src" and "alt", and use them in a little different way, along with removing the image element from the page.

```
<h1 id="logoImage">
    <a href="/" style="background-image: url('http://path-to-image.jpg')">
        Title of Site
    </a>
</h1>
```

I'm not too familiar with plain ol' JavaScript, so, this has me quite stumped.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: I'd probably google "get img src javascript" and "remove image javascript" and use the information on one of the 10 billion results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('load', function load(){
    var logo = document.getElementById('logoImage'),
        img,
        parent;

    if (!logo) {
        return;
    }

    img = logo.querySelector('img');

    if (!img) {
        return;
    }

    parent = img.parentNode;

    parent.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img.src + ')';
    parent.style.display = 'block';
    parent.style.width = img.width + 'px';
    parent.style.height = img.height + 'px';
    parent.textContent = img.alt;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q7brkkbt/1